# "Face" versus "have faced"

Tags: tense, present-perfect

Is there a semantic difference between the following two sentences?

> We now explain some of the issues we face in localizing such a bug using approaches other than ours.

> We now explain some of the issues we have faced in localizing such a bug using approaches other than ours.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that "we face" means you are going to talk about issues that are currently being dealt with. "We have faced" means you will discuss problems you have already encountered.

It's a very minor difference, and if you exchanged them in speech, most people would not notice.

Comment: Thanks, why you are using "exchanged"(past tense) in your comment?

Comment: @william007 That is an example of a Type 2 Conditional. In these sentences, the time is now or any time, and the situation is unreal. They are not based on fact, and they refer to an unlikely or hypothetical condition and its probable result

Comment: @william007 It is what somebody would call subjunctive, and somebody else would call irrealis mood. It is the same tense used in "If I were reach, I would live on Long Island." It doesn't express something that is going to happen; that is the reason why it is called _irrealis mood_.